# possible to use partial views for angular in asp.net core mvc?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

Im going over the Angular template in vs2017 and the ClientApp\app\components folder stores the html pieces for each component. And corresponding components typescript are defined like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent {
}
```

Is it possible to use an mvc partial view instead? If I could, would this be a bad idea?

Comment: Quite a bad question, pretty opinion based answers. Possible? Yes. Practical? No. You'd lose ability to bundle the templates in webpack, you'd lose intellisense support (coming in VS2015.5). Also you'd lose hot-module replacement feature. Angular, like most frameworks is a bit biased in the way its meant to be used, trying to get away to much from it just cause you extra work and overhead.

Comment: so the answer is "Yes", and "yes"...